# Access Super Stuck With Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I've been trying to combine two tables and cant get it done. Trying to add Number of Employees to the other table.
[image]
[image]

```
SELECT [Training History].JobID,(
       SELECT Job.Department 
       FROM Job 
       WHERE [Training History].JobID = Job.JobID) 
       AS Department, 
SUM([Expenditure]) AS ExpenditureOfJob 
     FROM [Training History] 
     GROUP BY [Training History].JobID,
(SELECT COUNT (*) AS [Number of Employees] 
     FROM Employee 
     GROUP BY JobID)
;
```

Also tried with;

```
(SELECT COUNT (*) AS [Number of Employees] 
     FROM Employee 
    WHERE [Training History].JobID = Employee.JobID
 GROUP BY JobID)
```

Says there is a syntax error on the final bit but I cannot find it.

Comment: Please, provide error message.

Comment: Are those really tables or queries? Usually aggregations are not saved in tables.

Comment: @Parfait both pictures are of queries, I made an intermediary one to try and work it all out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are running different grouped level aggregate queries (first by by *JobID* and *Department* and then second by only *JobID*), consider joining them as derived tables (i.e., nested subqueries in `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses):

```
SELECT agg1.JobID, agg1.Department, agg1.ExpenditureOfJob, agg2.[Number of Employees]
FROM
  (SELECT t.JobID, j.Department, SUM([Expenditure]) AS ExpenditureOfJob 
   FROM [Training History] t
   INNER JOIN Job j ON t.JobID = j.JobID
   GROUP BY t.JobID, j.Department) As agg1

   INNER JOIN
  (SELECT t.JobID, Count(*) AS [Number of Employees]
   FROM [Training History] t
   GROUP BY t.JobID) As agg2

ON agg1.JobID = agg2.JobID
```

Or join to your already saved queries:

```
SELECT agg1.*, agg2.[Number of Employees]
FROM
  mySavedQueryAgg1 as agg1

INNER JOIN
  mySavedQueryAgg2 as agg2

ON agg1.JobID = agg2.JobID
```

Comment: Top one works perfectly except the output of Number of Employees is incorrect it should be 4 in each job, but it displays 16 in each job.

Comment: Any idea why? I'm trying to spot it but I can't find the error.

Comment: Please show the underlying SQL of your screenshot queries. You might have another grouping not being show. Also, second one here is simply the join of the two screenshot queries (of course change *mySavedQueryAgg#* to actual names).

Comment: Found it, I changed out the agg2 to the following (edited your post)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a **simple `JOIN`**. ([More info here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6))

To combine the data in your examples tables based on `JobID`:

```
SELECT
  [Training History].*,
  JobID.*
FROM
  [Training History] left **inner join** JobID
  ON [Training History].JobID = Job.JobID
```

This is onlt the most simple form of a join; there's a lot more you can do that will probably apply better to your real data and needs.  Google "Joining tables in Access".

Also Access's Query Designer makes it a lot easier to accomplish tasks like this since it "writes" the SQL for you.

Comment: @Parfait indeed, thx. (I've been working in SQL Server all week...) ...another example of advantages to using the Query Designers in Access!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what ashleedawg said is true. However, since you are using MS Access, that type of SQL string will most likely not work correctly.

To the best of my knowledge, no version of MS Access supports SQL in that context. (I may be wrong about that though)

If what was mentioned did not work, try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Training History]
INNER JOIN Employee ON Employee.JobID = [Training History].JobID
```

EDIT:

For simplicity (this is in design view of the query [Design Tab]):

[image]

Comment: Added a little more to the explanation, hope that helps.